# C# How to convert one file format to another format?

Tags: file-conversion

I have two pipe-delimited text files (say, A.txt and B.txt).

Below is A.txt file format, a standard format (can think of as Universal Set)

```
"EmpId"|"FName"|"LName"|"Sex"|"DOB"|"SSN"|"TagId1"|"TagId2"
```

Below is B.txt file (can think of Sub Set) with column and 2 records.

```
"SSN"|"LName"|"FName"|"DOB"|"Sex"|"EmpId"
"123"|"Barrat"|"Alanzon"|"1983"|"F"|"4455"
"678"|"Alexia"|"Timothy"|"1975"|"M"|"2222"||"baz"
```

I need to convert B.txt into A.txt format’s columns order.
Expected result is:

```
"EmpId"|"FName"|"LName"|"Sex"|"DOB"|"SSN"|"TagId1"|"TagId2"
"4455"|"Alanzon"|"Barrat"|"F"|"1983"|"123"|||
"2222"|" Timothy "|" Alexia"|"M"|"1975"|"678"||"baz"
```

How to go about it?

Comment: first try to format your Q

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you need to do this in a program you're writing Or are you looking for a tool that does this? What OS are you running?

Comment: This seems like a trivial `awk` script

Comment: Why are there spaces around `Timothy` and `Alexia` in the output, when  it's not in the input? There's no similar modification for `Alanzon` and `Barrat`.

Comment: Trying to write C# code. The spaces around Timothy and Alexia are typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the two formats are basically the same, except the columns are reordered, I would recommend just reading `B.txt` into a dictionary (with the column name as the key) and then printing this dictionary to a file, with the columns in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{print $6, $3, $2, $5, $4, $1, $7, $8}' B.txt > A.txt
```